# Is there a way in Excel to get required data from a database to another workbook where we process it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database with different values. It is object based, so object "A" will have certain data and so on for other objects. It has almost 200,000 lines, but I only need the data from one object that is given as input in my tool's database. I want my tool to look in the huge database and pull the required data into its own database.

This huge database is also in the same workbook of my tool, but it has to be updated regularly and makes my tool open too slowly. I want the database in a different workbook, and the required data to be copied, according to an input object, into a sheet of my tool, where I will work on it.

Suppose the huge database (let's call it Workbook A) is as follows:

```
object  var1   var2   var3   var4    var5
A
B
C
D
E
```

Input workbook is B

sheet 1 where we give input

lets say input is A

The input database is in Sheet2:

```
object  var1   var2   var3   var4    var5
A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use VLOOKUP and reference your other workbook or you can use VBA and ADO to access the data. The VBA ADO method is shown below. You must set a reference to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects**.

```
Dim DBWorkbook As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Sub get_data() 'set reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    DBWorkbook = "C:\MyHugeDatabaseWorkbook.xlsx"
    'lets assume everything is happening on Sheet2, Row2
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    LookupObject = ws.Cells(2, 1)

    'connect to huge database workbook
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBWorkbook & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;"""
    'get data for object
    rs.Open "Select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE [object]='" & LookupObject & "'", con, adOpenStatic
    'fill in sheet with data, if it exists in the database worksheet
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ws.Cells(2, 2) = rs("var1")
        ws.Cells(2, 3) = rs("var2")
        ws.Cells(2, 4) = rs("var3")
        ws.Cells(2, 5) = rs("var4")
        ws.Cells(2, 6) = rs("var5")
    End If
    'cleanup
    rs.Close
    con.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    'this needs error trapping once you have it working
End Sub
```

You would also do yourself a **huge** favor by putting your database into Access or SQL Server and referencing it from there.